# Print a variable with multi-line value in shell?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, environment-variables

In Bash (or other shells) how can I print an environment variable which has a multi-line value?

```
text='line1
line2'
```

I know a simple usual `echo $text` won't work out of the box. 
Would some $IFS tweak help?

My current workaround is something like `ruby -e 'print ENV["text"]'`. 
Can this be done in pure shell? I was wondering if `env` command would take an unresolved var name but it does not seem to.

Comment: Why bend over backwards with backticks?  Just do `text='line1<newline>line2'` (so the assignment spans two literal lines of text), or `text=$'line1\nline2'` if you are happy with restricted portability.

Comment: with bash, the way to get that text into a variable is `text=$'line1\nline2'`

Comment: @WilliamPursell I knew it was simpler than that I tried heredoc first but that didn't work..but of course a plain multiline string is simpler..it's just very late to refresh my bash memories. thanks.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Same solution as always.

```
echo "$text"
```

Comment: sorry, how is this different from echo $text?

Comment: There are double quotes, which inhibits word splitting in bash.

Comment: Here's another clue about word splitting: `python -c "import sys; print sys.argv" $text` produces: `['-c', 'line1', 'line2']`, while if we double-quote the final argument, we get `['-c', 'line1\nline2']`.

Answer (score 4):

```
export TEST="A\nB\nC"
echo $TEST
```

gives output:

```
A\nB\nC
```

but:

```
echo -e $TEST
A
B
C
```

So, the answer seems to be the '**-e**' parameter to **echo**, assuming that I understand your question correctly.

Comment: Thanks, that's nice indeed.. however in my scenario the var contains a genuine LF char rather than the escape sequence. Clarifying the question now.

Comment: While this might work in general, in Docker, RUN echo -e blah   produces   "-e blah"